# Why is there no OpenJDK 8 packaged for guix?

Tags: guix, guixsd

When I search the Guix repository there are only versions of OpenJDK from 9 and up, but I want to install OpenJDK 8. Why is there no version 8?

```
$ guix search openjdk | recsel -p name,version
name: openjdk
version: 9.181

name: openjdk
version: 14.0

name: openjdk
version: 13.0

name: openjdk
version: 12.33

name: openjdk
version: 11.28

name: openjdk
version: 10.46

name: icedtea
version: 1.13.13

name: java-marlin-renderer
version: 0.9.4.2

name: icedtea
version: 3.7.0

name: icedtea
version: 2.6.13
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently OpenJDK 7 and 8 are named `icedtea`:

```
$ guix environment --ad-hoc icedtea --pure
$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_161"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 3.7.0) (guix build 1.8.0_161-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.161-b12, mixed mode)
```